# Playlist shortcode, prevent repeat disable

Tags: loop, playlist

I'm using the WordPress playlist shortcode to present a few audio samples on a given page. For example:

[playlist images="false" artists="false" ids="542,543"]
The shortcode, by default loops the playlist. The [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Playlist_Shortcode) on the codex doesn't show an option to disable autorepeat/looping of the playlist via a parameter.

I need to disable playlist looping; i.e. play only once (play 1,2,3 and stop). I tried to use this code, but it stops after playing the first track and does not go to the second track, but I need the playlist to play one time all track and then stop at the end.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
?>
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.mejs-mediaelement video').on('ended', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this)[0].player.pause();
    });
});
</script>
<?php
},99);
```

Any suggestions on how to acheive this?